# Structs on inheritance

Tags: solidity, storage, struct, inheritance

Can an inherited contract have access to his parent's struct variables?

I'm trying the code from below but I can't access the struct defined on `ContractA`, so I don't know if it's not possible at all or if I'm missing something.

`AppStorage.sol`

```js
struct AppStorage {
    uint num;
    uint num2;
}
```

`ContractA.sol`

```js
import './AppStorage.sol';

contract ContractA {
    AppStorage internal s;

    function setNum() public {
        s.num = 20;
    }

    function setNum2() public {
        s.num2 = 15;
    }
}
```

`ContractB.sol`

```js
contract ContractB is ContractA {
    function getNum2() public view returns(uint) {
        return s.num2; // -----> returns 0
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
`sample-script.js`

```js
const ContA = await ethers.getContractFactory('ContractA');
const contA = await ContA.deploy();
await contA.deployed();

await contA.setNum();
await contA.setNum2();

const ContB = await ethers.getContractFactory('ContractB');
const contB = await ContB.deploy();
await contB.deployed();

let num = await contB.getNum2();
console.log('num: ', num);
```

[image: pic]

Comment: I ran your code on remix and it works fine for me. Are you sure you called `setNum2()` and not `setNum()`?

Comment: Double checked just in case and it's all correct. I edited the question and posted the `js` file where I do the callings and the command output. @egjlmn1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deployed 2 different contracts, `contA` of type `ContractA` and `contB` of type `ContractB`.

You set the `s.num2` of `contA` and checked the num of `contB`.
it's like creating two objects, each has its own address and its own state variables.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but if `ContractB` is supposed to be an extension of `ContractA` you should only deploy ContractB and have only one instance of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So my problem was on my understanding of how inheritance works. I'll go back to the docs.